# Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted to string

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, clob

I am trying to access CLOB type field's data from the Oracle database in CodeIgniter but getting the following error:

```
Message: Object of class OCI-Lob could not be converted to string
```

After var_dump getting result as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Oracle “CLOB” (Character Large Object) is a data type used to
>   store up to 4 Gigabytes of text.
>
> To get the CLOB contents you will need to call the load() or read()
>   methods on the returned object. The latter will require the length of
>   data to read in bytes but has the advantage of not being limited by
>   the script memory limit.

Example:

```
$result->FORUM_DESC->load();
```

or

```
$result->FORUM_DESC->read(2000);
```

[Source.](http://www.mkfoster.com/2010/09/22/how-to-get-the-contents-of-an-oracle-clob-data-field-in-php/)